Docker-compose is able to compile program but is unable to open link to Local host
I have a basic Django project that I have put into a docker container.
Currently I have it running on https locally just for the development phase because it is a requirement.
When I run my program without docker it opens successfully on https://127.0.0.1:8000. Which is the address the message says its currently running on.
But when I use the same logic on my docker container after running docker-compose up the container compiles but I am unable to load the web page. When I try to run the address from the docker container I just get the generic site cannot be reached error.
Link I used to get https during development:
Docker-compose.yml
version: "3.8"
   
services:
    django:
        build: .
        container_name: frontend
        command: python manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file cert.pem --key-file key.pem

        volumes:
            - .:/usr/src/app
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        depends_on:
            - pgdb
    pgdb:
        image: postgres
        container_name: backend
        environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.12.3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install django

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'location',
    'rest_framework',
    'django_extensions',
 
]

I tried to change the port number but it still didn't work.

In Docker you almost always need to set a process to listen on 0.0.0.0 and not 127.0.0.1; see for example Docker app server ip address 127.0.0.1 difference of 0.0.0.0 ip.  In standard Django you'd need to do something like CMD ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000.  Does a similar option work for your setup?

I reread my stuff and it actually compiles on https://localhost:8000 but I need to run the commands: python manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file cert.pem --key-file key.pem in order to compile the certificates that let me use https.

any help would be appreciated

I figured out the issue as pointed out. I just needed to specify a address for docker.
command: python manage.py runserver_plus 0.0.0.0:8000 --cert-file cert.pem --key-file key.pem
adding the 0.0.0.0.8000 fixed my issue
